# how to install gganimate in R

Tags: r

I am trying to install gganimate in Rstudio, but failed.
Before submitting this question, I have already searched for similar question.
I tried the following code people recommend, but it does not work.

```
library(devtools) 
library(RCurl)
library(httr) 

set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )

devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")

devtools::install_github("thomasp85/gganimate")
```

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
>     schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid

some people suggest to install rtools and change path manually, I did that but not working:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:/Rtools/bin/",
                    "C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin", sep = ";"))

Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/")
```

Anybody know the solution?

Comment: I'm getting `Installation failed: Timeout was reached: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds`. Perhaps a temporary Github issue?

Comment: it looks that you got different error message. I have R3.5.1, not sure if the latest R version cause the problem. I tried last week, same error, may not be a temp issue.

Comment: @user3229139: i've just tried installing from GitHub on my Win 10 PC running R 3.5.1. Everything was ok. Have you tried installing `ggplot` before `ggannimate`?

Comment: I installed ggplot2 already. But I am using a corporate PC, is it a firewall issue?

Comment: That's actually very likely. Can you install any other libraries from Github?